# jQuery switch 2 divs by OS

Tags: jquery, operating-system

I use jQuery for a couple of days now and I have a problem for a project.
I have 3 Divs: 1 Download Div for Windows installation, 1 for OSX download and 1 Div that contains these two.
I already have the script to check the OS but now I want that if i the user has mac the OSX version of the download moves from the 2nd to the 1st so that WIndows DL is at the bottom and Mac first but only if you are using mac. I tried .prependTo and appendTo

```
<div id="container">
<div windows>
<div class="oslogo">
 OS logo
  </div>
  <div class="download">
 DL img
</div>
 <div class="host">
 DL Host version
  </div>
</div>
```

```
<div mac>
<div class="oslogo">
 OS logo
  </div>
  <div class="download">
 DL img
</div>
 <div class="host">
 DL Host version
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1) $("#mac").prependto("#container");
});
</script
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want to detach the element first i.e.

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $(document).ready(function(){ 
        if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Mac")!=-1){
            $("#mac").detach().prependTo("#container");
        }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

thanks for your reply but it still doesnt work i had to change your code because it changed the whole document (dont know why) and i use this code now:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){ 
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
$("#mac").detach();
if (navigator.appVersion.indexOf("Win")!=-1) 
$("#mac").appendto("#container");
});
</script
```

(i dont have a mac to test so i have ".indexOf("Win")" in it)

so and this script now detaches #mac but doesn't prepend it again